# How to replace a value from an array list dynamically when a user edits the array of values?

Tags: android

How do I replace a value from an array list dynamically when the user edits the array of values? I used `arr_list.set(count,"replace value")` inside button `click.Action` done by using the button click event. So I used count for index of `arr_list`. I have an issue as I click the button it replaces all the values in `arr_list`. I want to replace particular edit values done by user.

if (v == right) {

```
 if (riskList.size() == 0) {

        } else 
              {
            try {
                riskList.set(count2,key.getText().toString());
                Log.i("dfDF", "" + count2);
                key.setText(riskList.get(count2).toString());
                toGetIndex = key.toString();
                int indexPlus = riskList.indexOf(toGetIndex);
                risk.setText(descList.get(count2).toString());
                totalRiskin.setText(count2 + 1 + "/" + totalRisks);

            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(SalesEditActivity.this,
                        "There is no next element", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
            count2 = count2 + 1;

        }
    }
```

I have used previous and next button to display array list values according to index.ie count. I also want edit array list values,it will be replace the current index value.

Comment: arr_list.set(count,"replace value") should work ! Provide your code where you are facing the problem .

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring your array list as static.